# Using struct for multiple arguments for pthread_create, but struct member pointer returns null(or seg. fault error) inside function for pthread_create

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, pthreads, pthread-join

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct arg_struct{
    char* arg1;
    char* arg2;
};

void *find_substr_count(void *context){
    char* newStr;   
    struct arg_struct* arguments = context;
    newStr = (*arguments).arg1;
    printf("newstr: %s\n", (*newStr));
}//end find_substr_count

main(void){
    pthread_t thread1;
    /* Create independent threads each of which will execute function */
    int iret1; 

    FILE* fp;
    char* str1;
    char* str2;
    char* str3;
    char* str4;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    int count = 0;  

    fp = fopen("./string.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    read = getline(&str1, &len, fp);
    str3 = str1;
    printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", read);
    read = getline(&str2, &len, fp);
    str4 = str2;
    printf("%s\n", str1);
    printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", read);
    printf("%s\n", str2);
    struct arg_struct args;
    args.arg1 = str3;
    args.arg2 = str4;
    free(str1);
    free(str2); 

    iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, *find_substr_count, &args);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    printf("Thread 1 returns:%d", iret1);
    fclose(fp);

    exit(0);
}//end main
```

My c program reads two lines from a text file and initializes them as str1, and str2. Then I set them to str3, and str4, and free the memory on str1, and str2. I set str3, and str4 as the members of my struct "arg_struct" so that I can have multiple arguments go in to my function: "*find_substr_count((void* context))", after calling pthread_create. But when I try to print the arg1, after dereferencing, I get "(null)" as the output. When I try to print arg2, after dereferencing, I get a segmentation fault error. I feel like this is a pointer problem but I can't find out what I'm doing wrong. I am doing this on a a linux VM with 4 CPUs, that's why I can use POSIX pthreads. I need to get the right values for my function. Please help!

I have tried to use st1, and str2 directly to the function, and to free them after pthread_join, i get seg fault. I have tried using args.arg1 = &str3, args.arg2 = &str4, and i get a seg fault before printing length of str2 in output. I have tried using void* as the data type for arg_struct inside pthread_create but I get a compiler error: "cannot convert to pointer type". Im expecting for my program to print the first line of the text file, to print in my "*find_substr_count((void* context))" function. The text file is in the same directory of number_substring.c and is called string.txt.

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.  Also compile with all warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra`).

Comment: Initialize your pointers to `NULL` at their definition, and see if that solves the issue. If it does, crash is probably because of `getline`.

Comment: Also, always check return values of any IO (except printing to stdout/stderr). Crash may be due to unhandled error.

Comment: You're `free`'ing memory (`str1`, `str2`) that you then access via the structure members.  That's undefined behaviour.  Also, if you read the [`getline` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline) you'll see that the first parameter must refer to a pointer that is either `null` or valid -- yours are uninitialized.

Comment: Guys thanks so much for the help! I got it to work after the changes: I initialized str1 and str2 to NULL, I freed str1 and str2 after pthread_join() . I removed str3 and str4, i set args.arg1 = str1; and args.arg2 = str2; . I changed the printf line inside the function: void *find_substr_count(void *context), to "printf("newstr: %s\n", (newStr));" , so I got rid of the dereference there. Im so glad, I was stuck on that for a while :)